# show loaded content on scroll jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a page where I am grabbing data from my sql database table and loading it. The need is to load data on scroll. Because I am grabbing data from database table, it becomes hard to figure out which row is already loaded and load data other than that. So is there any way based on window height I can scroll down to show more data - other than setting overflow to scroll for the body or main container? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of a state variable that tells your php script what offset to return.

```
var offset = 0;
var loading = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function(){

    if($('#element').offset().top >= ($(window).scrollTop() - $(window).height()))
    {
        loading = true;
        $.ajax({
            //all your ajax settings here
            data: {offset: offset}
            success: function(data){
                // add data to dom here
                loading = false;
                offset += 1;
            }
        });
    }

});
```

That way you pass offset to your script and return the data relative to this number, however you choose to interpret that.

Offset being used in mysql. I will give a php example since you didn't specify language:

```
$limit = "0, 20";
if(isset($_POST['offset']))
{
    // obviously you should sanitize this, but for example we
    // ignore that for now.

    $limit = ($_POST['offset'] * 20) .", 20";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT $limit";
// run your query and echo the results
```

You see, the offset passed just alters the query to grab the next chunk of data. In javascript we increment this number on success so the next time the window reaches the bottom it will pass the next offset to php and return the next increment. We use the arbitrary number 20 assuming you're returning some kind of data that has rows, like blog entries, images, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Dont mind me sounding naive but what is the offset are you talking about?